# How to save the plot in image format

Tags: flask, plotly

Here 'graphJSON' is a variable used for plotting the graph and how can i capture(image format) the graph using this variable?

```
graphJSON = json.dumps(data, cls=plotly.utils.PlotlyJSONEncoder)
plotly.io.to_image(graphJSON, format=None,
                   scale=None, width=None, height=None)
```

Comment: You could use `fig.to_plotly_json()` to get the JSON which has all the data required to generate your plot and then pass its `data` and `layout` attribute into a HTML template (e.g. using Jinja2), see https://blog.heptanalytics.com/2018/08/07/flask-plotly-dashboard/ for an example.

Comment: In the above link mentioned, the function returns a variable named 'graphJSON' , how can i save the plot as image using that variable? any clue?

Comment: That helped me a lot....thanks mate!!!.........any clue on above query?

Comment: https://medium.com/@plotlygraphs/plotly-py-end-of-summer-updates-5422c98b9058 but using a HTML template with the code will look better and is a more robust solution.

Comment: yep, but in some cases we always don't need an interactive plot but just static so i am looking to use image save format..... how could we use that returned variable to save as image.....i looked through the code but i couldn't solve it mate

Comment: The function returns the binary image data, base64 encode it and add it to your HTML file.

Comment: Could I have some code format......?

Comment: Please change the code in your question to get a [MCVE] and I'll post an answer.

Comment: I have changed it mate.....May i know if anything more to be included ?

Comment: Hey There , any idea how to achieve the image capture?.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Install [plotly-orca](https://github.com/plotly/orca)
- Create your plotly figure
- Convert the figure to PNG
- Convert the binary PNG to base64 encoded bytes
- Decode the base64 bytes to `ascii` and pass them to your Jinja2 template

**Full code**

```
import plotly
import base64
import jinja2

# create the graph
scatter = plotly.graph_objs.Scatter(x=[1, 2, 3], y=[2, 1, 3])
layout = plotly.graph_objs.Layout()
fig = plotly.graph_objs.Figure([scatter], layout)

# convert graph to JSON
fig_json = fig.to_json()

# convert graph to PNG and encode it
png = plotly.io.to_image(fig)
png_base64 = base64.b64encode(png).decode('ascii')

# definition of the Jinja2 template
template = """<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="data:image/png;base64,{{ png_base64 }}" />

    <div id='divPlotly'></div>
    <script>
        var plotly_data = {{ plotly_data }}
        Plotly.react('divPlotly', plotly_data.data, plotly_data.layout);
    </script>
</body>

</html>"""

# generate the HTML page
with open('new_plot.html', 'w') as f:
    f.write(jinja2.Template(template).render(png_base64=png_base64, 
                                             plotly_data=fig_json))
```

Answer (score 3):

The marked answer is correct. This is just an FYI that you can simplify the fig to png_base64 conversion by converting the figure directly to an image.

This:

```
png_base64 = base64.b64encode(fig.to_image()).decode('ascii')
```

Instead of this:

```
# convert graph to JSON
fig_json = fig.to_json()

# convert graph to PNG and encode it
png = plotly.io.to_image(fig)
png_base64 = base64.b64encode(png).decode('ascii')
```

Comment: Thank you, would be helpful for others too  :)